# PubSub Message Attributes in Spring Cloud GCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

GCP PubSub allows message attributes to be added to PubSub messages, and these attributes can be read on the subscriber side using the "getAttributes" method in the [PubSubMessage](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/pubsub/model/PubsubMessage.html) class:

`Map<String, String> attributesMap = pubsubMessage.getAttributes()`

Does Spring Cloud GCP PubSub allow access to these attributes using the provided Spring classes? I realize that I could probably extract the actual pubsub message but that seems to defeat the purpose of using Spring to do the message management.